# How do I use a terms/colors file

Tags: gnome-terminal

Working with Linux Mint Cinnamon and Gnome Terminal, how do I use the term/colors files available from here:

http://dotshare.it/category/terms/colors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the files there are [X resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources) files for [Rxvt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rxvt) (most of them specifically for Urxvt, the Unicode-aware version of Rxvt). They are not generic terminal emulator configuration files, they are configuration file for that specific terminal emulator. They can't be used by Gnome-terminal.

If you want to try them out, install the `rxvt-unicode` package. Download one of the `Xdefaults` file and run

```
XENVIRONMENT=/path/to/Xdefaults urxvt
```

If you want to make one the default:

1. Many of these files are badly written and will work with the explicit `XENVIRONMENT`, but not the `.Xresources` method. If there are lines that contain comments starting with `#`, remove them or replace the `#` with `!`, which is the comment start character in X resource files. Also, if there are any lines beginning with `*` or `?`, add `Rxvt` before it. For example http://dotshare.it/dots/1042/ should start with

   ```
   ! rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.15 - released: 2012-01-21
   Rxvt*color0: #0C0C0C
   …
   ```

   Whitespace doesn't matter but capitalization does.
2. Copy the corrected file to `~/.Xresources`. This file is loaded when you log in. To apply the settings now, run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`.

Comment: Giles - thank you for your detailed answer.  I have marked your answer as correct although I have not tested it as I am not using Rxvt.   I realize now that I should have asked my question in a more general sense.   I hope this answer will be of use to people using Rxvt.